# How can I install feem on my system?

Tags: software-installation

I'm using 18.04 Linux operating system on my device. How to install Feem software on my system?

Comment: I mean feem is a software that is used for transfer files between two computers. I just need the terminal command for installing feem software

Comment: The web site provides an appimage. You're basically asking how to use an appimage. Hence the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Download the installer files from here: https://feem.io/#download, then

1. Umcompress: `tar -xvf <file> -C /to/directory/of/choice`
2. Make installer executable: `sudo chmod +x <Feem Installer File>.sh`
3. Run installer found in there, ends with `.sh` extension: `./<Feem Installer File>.sh`

   - if it fails run with `sudo ./<Feem Installer File>.sh`

See: https://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/09/feem-alternative-shareit-for-ubuntu-linux.html